# reading value actual from xml path

Tags: xpath

I have the following xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? >  
<sql>  
  <Assoc name="sql">  
    <RecArray name="contents">  
      <Record name="contents">  
        <String name="PackType" > < value actual="P" />< /String >  
        <String name="SerialNumber" > < value actual="0002" />< /String >  
        <String name="VersionNumber" > < value actual="02" /></ String >  
      </Record>  
    </RecArray>  
  </Assoc>  
</sql>
```

how can i get the values of each of the String nodes like i need to know the value inside the node of "SerialNumber"
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to get all `<value>` elements inside each `<String>` element, you can try this XPath query :

```
/sql/Assoc/RecArray/Record/String/value
```

precise path will be better performance wise. If you're looking for simpler query, this will also work :

```
//String/value
```

or if you mean by *values of each of the String nodes* is value of `actual` attribute, you can do this way :

```
/sql/Assoc/RecArray/Record/String/value/@actual
```

Finally, if none of above meet your requirement, please update the question and provide expected output from sample XML posted.

Answer (score -1):

i figured it out
as it is multi String elements (that was clear in the question), i should use the following

```
/sql/Assoc/RecArray/Record/String[2]/value/@actual
```